# Unable to rename layers in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I am not a new user...but I'm not an expert either.  With that said...I know that it is very easy to rename a layer.  All you need to do is double click on it and rename!

The problem is Illustrator for some reason is no longer letting me do this.  I'm not even sure how to go to the menu to do it the "long way".  I've restarted my computer, Illustrator and anything else that I can think of.

Anyone have any ideas?  I'd really appreciate hearing from you.  This is so easy I can't believe I have to ask this!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Double clicking layer name highlights layer name so I can rename it. Highlighting layer in the Layer Panel and going to the"hamburger" menu (top right corner of layer panel) and going to Options for [Layer name] opens dialog box that I can rename layer (or Object even). Did you try and alt/option click the new layer icon at the bottom of the layer panel ? That should open the same dialog box where you can rename. Otherwise maybe a screenshot of your layer panel ? You might have to re-install Illustrator ? Seems like a local problem for you-

Comment: Trash prefs.. and relaunch AI. Merely relaunching retains possibly corrupt preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to open up the layers panel.

If you can't see it, or can't edit layer names in it, there's something wrong with your copy of AI.

Or..

Maybe something's wrong with a particular file. A lot of strange "bugs" people discover with corrupted files, sometimes linked to pre-CC artwork, or artwork imported from other formats (SVG, CDR, etc).

Try creating a new blank file and retrace the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

The double click to change a layer name no longer works using a mac in Illustrator CC 2023. It's a much longer process but you can still edit the layer name.

1. Choose layer options - hamburger top right
2. Click on options for
3. Change name in pop-up box

[image: Choose layer options - hamburger top right]

[image: Click on options for]

[image: Change name in pop-up box]

Comment: This question was posted in 2021... long before AI2023 was released. But... your process does work in *any* version of Illustrator.